# Cause=slf4j dependency confiliction - NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, slf4j

I have 2 application context which one import another(appContext-middleware -> appContext-core)

when i test appContext-core with test case below it works fine,

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext-core.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class DaoTest {
    @Autowired
    UsersDao usersDao;

    @Test
    public void testUsers() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertNotNull(usersDao);   
    }

}
```

and also without importing appContext-core appContext-middleware works fine too

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext-middleware.xml")
public class TestSomeService {
    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void getBeans() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(someService);
    }
}
```

But when i import appContext-core inside appContext-middleware, bean initiations fail as follow

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.project.tr.some.core.dao.impl.someGenericDaoImpl.init(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.project.tr.some.core.dao.impl.someGenericDaoImpl.init(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
```

applicationContext-core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/project.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.tr.core.dao"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class=
            "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.tr.core.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.idle_test_period">120</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.max_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.timeout">120</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">latin5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">latin5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${database.connection.url}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${database.connection.driver}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${database.connection.username}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${database.connection.password}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.sql_exception_converter">
                    com.project.tr.core.exception.SQLExceptionTranslator
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${database.connection.driver}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${database.connection.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${database.connection.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${database.connection.password}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="acquireIncrement">
            <value>${database.connection.acquireIncrement}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize">
            <value>${database.connection.initialPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxIdleTime">
            <value>${database.connection.maxIdleTime}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize">
            <value>${database.connection.maxPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxStatements">
            <value>${database.connection.maxStatements}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">
            <value>${database.connection.minPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">
            <value>${database.connection.idleConnectionTestPeriod}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery">
            <value>${database.connection.preferredTestQuery}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime">
            <value>${database.connection.maxAdministrativeTaskTime}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout">
            <value>${database.connection.unreturnedConnectionTimeout}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">
            <value>${database.connection.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Template Defintion -->
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        <property name="jdbcExceptionTranslator" ref="jdbcExceptionTranslator"/>

    </bean>

    <!-- Spring Data Access Exception Translator Defintion -->
    <bean id="jdbcExceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

        <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager Definition -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

        <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <tx:attributes>
                <tx:method name="get" read-only="true"/>
                <tx:method name="*"/>
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>
        <context:annotation-config/>
        <bean id="transactionProxy" abstract="true"
              class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                    <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                    <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                    <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext-middleware

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:applicationContext-core.xml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.tr..middleware"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

I think it fails because of propertyConfigurer in core, somehow it can't be used while imported by middleware but I didn't understand why,

Comment: You have some classpath issues, and I'm not sure if it has to do with that `<import />`.

Comment: i realized that exception comes from java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be SLF4J API jars. Make sure you have no duplicate jars in your classpath. If exists exclude them and add these dependencies to your classpath this should be suitable with the hibernate version that you use.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yeah you are right , the bug isn't from spring or hibernate as I thought. Different slf4j dependency versions comes from core and middleware modules, these versions causes confliction. I excluded them from pom and add the dependencies you offered and it worked. Thanks